# How do I summarise data in RStudio using dplyr group functions?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset composed of postcodes, Local Authorities and median broadband speeds. I'm trying to use RStudio and dplyr to count the number of postcodes within each local authority with median broadband speeds of at least 10 mbits per second. My data looks like this:

| Postcode | LA | Median |
| --- | --- | --- |
| IP300AT | Babergh | 0.2 |
| GU344EA | East Hampshire | 0.2 |

I used the following code to try and do this:

```
Broadband %>% group_by(LA) %>% count(LA, Median=">10") %>% View()
```

But it did not work, what code should I be using? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
result <- Broadband %>%
             group_by(LA) %>% 
             filter(Median >=10) %>%
             summarise(count = n())
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sum` to perform the count.

```
library(dplyr)

result <- Broadband %>% group_by(LA) %>% summarise(count = sum(Median >= 10))
```

In base R and `data.table` -

```
#data.table
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(count = sum(Median >= 10)), LA]

#Base R
aggregate(Median~LA, Broadband, function(x) sum(x >= 10))
```

Comment: Thanks so much! One follow up question, what code would I use if I wanted to work out the total number of postcodes within each LA, how many of those had speeds of more than 10 mbits, and how many that is as a proportion of the total number of postcodes within each LA?

Comment: Every postcode has only one row? You can try - `result <- Broadband %>% 
  group_by(LA) %>% summarise(count = sum(Median >= 10), total = n(), proportion = mean(Median >= 10))`

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much again, I really appreciate the help.